# SKU is not working properly in searching

Tags: catalogsearch, magento2.3.4

i have search product,
my product sku is **"wim7960"**
when i search wim many products are display, but when i search 7960, no result show,
only show "**Your search returned no results**."

in site not used any search related extension, working in magento 2.3 default search.

Comment: You can try to follow the execution until getting the final sql request. From that sql request you will be able to see why it's not working and to start fixing issue.

Comment: @Claims i do not understood your answer properly, can you please describe me?

Comment: I'm just telling you to debug step by step with xdebug from yout controller called by the search until catching the final sql request  made. May be the final request will make sku == 77 instead of something like sku like '%77%' or something like that. We can't know.